# Lambda - "errorType": "Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

i have a python script in which i have included a handler like this [lambda_handler] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLcFG.png) and i have a dockerfile[DockerFile used to build image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbvhn.png) which i am using to make a container image which is pushed to ECR and used to make a lambda function.

The problem is i am getting is

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint",
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 86339395-a02e-4122-b54e-9f80a7bfbd40 Error: exec: \"lambda_function.lambda_handler\": executable file not found in $PATH"
}
```

i am just not sure what to put as the entry point. i have tried different solution like changing the architecture and build

as i am using a M2 MAC i thought the architecture might be the problem and changed the build

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t lambda-function .
```

and tried but still getting the invalid entry when tested in lambda

Answer (score 0):

As per AWS documentation you will need to move the "handler" file to Root Path. Which is defined with "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}".

Use the COPY command to copy the function code and runtime dependencies to {LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}, a Lambda-defined environment variable.

AWS Documentation: [Python Deployment with Container Images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html)

Thus, the Dockerfile should look like:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12

# Copy requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install the specified packages
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy function code
COPY lambda_function.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "lambda_function.handler" ]
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the error you're encountering is related to the entry point specified for your Lambda function . Lambda expects the entry point to be a Python file and a function within that file , but it seems like it's unable to find the executable file named lambda_function.lambda_handler .

```
FROM python:3.12

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy lambda function code
COPY lambda_function.py .

# Install dependencies if any
# RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Specify the command to run your script
CMD ["lambda_function.lambda_handler"]
```